EPR effect, non-locality, positivism and realism
In the framework of EPRB experiments, has an experimental verification been performed of the conservation of 2-time correlations of Bob's photons polarization despite Alice's polarization measurements?
More precisely, the article Each moment of time a new universe by Aharonov, Popescu and Tollaksen, presents:

a T-symmetric formulation of the temporal “evolution” of a quantum
system which does not evolve (H=0)
a very important consequence predicted thanks to this formulation concerning the interpretation of the EPRB experiment.

This very interesting 8 pages article is quickly read and a video is presented by Popescu. Thanks to their 2-state vector T-symmetric formalism, Aharonov, Popescu and Tollaksen notably highlight the following facts:

as long as no quantum measurement is carried out on a given quantum system (undergoing a H=0 Hamiltonian evolution) the 2-time measurement O(t2) - O(t1) between instants t1 and t2 vanishes whatever the observable O. This proves the existence of a time correlation between successive states of a quantum system as long as it does not undergo any quantum measurement.

On the other hand, the correlation O(t2) - O(t1) = 0 is broken between instants t1 and t2 respectively preceding and following a quantum measurement of the considered system (except in the specific cases when the measurement result is an eigenstate of O).


Concerning an EPRB type experiment, this document indicates §5 Measurements on EPR state:

The break, on Alice's side, of the 2-time correlations between instants t1 and t2 preceding and following a quantum measurement by Alice. Indeed, except in a particular case when the measurement result is an eigenvalue of O, the 2-time correlation O(t2) - O(t1) = 0 is lost.

The conservation, on Bob's side, of the 2-time correlations O(t2) - O(t1) = 0 as long as Bob does not make any measurements on his side.


Thus, the 2-state vector time-symmetric formalism shows the asymmetry of the quantum state obtained, during an EPRB experiment, after a measurement carried out on one side only. That asymmetry is not highlighted in the standard formulation. Consequently, the standard one-state vector time-asymmetric formalism suggests a (hidden) relativistic causality violation. On the contrary, the conservation of the 2-time correlation in the 2-state vector formalism seems providing a proof that, on Bob's side, nothing happens as long as only Alice carries out quantum measurements on her side.
This seems providing a testable prediction allowing us to decide between:

In a realist interpretation of the EPRB experiment, the quantum state is interpreted as the model of an objective physical state (cf. On the reality of the quantum state) and the reduction of the wave packet as instantaneous, non-local AND objective (cf. Bohm, Bell, Goldstein, Bricmont,  Scarani, Valentini, Selleri, Percival, Towler,  Hemmick, Aspect, Special Relativity and possible Lorentz violations consistently coexist in Aristotle space-time ...)
In a positivist interpretation of the EPRB experiment, on the contrary, the instantaneous and "non-local reduction of the wave packet" is interpreted as an irreversible and local record of information, hence up to be read by an observer carrying out the measurement (cf. Peres, Fuchs, Rovelli, Jaynes (1)...) without objective change of Bob's photons state when only Alice performs polarization measurements on her photons.

When only Alice carries out measurements on her side, the prediction of the conservation of the 2-time correlation on Bob's side, resulting from the 2-state vector time-symmetric formalism, decides in favor of the positivist interpretation of the EPR effect. This interpretation thus becomes a falsifiable physical postulate instead of a pure philosophical question.
Such an experimental verification seems solving a 40 years debate between positivist and realist interpretations of Bell's inequalities violation. Hence, this experimental validation seems deserving to be carried out if it has not already been done.
Here is my question. In the EPRB experiment, has an experimental verification been performed of the conservation of 2-time quantum correlations on Bob's side as long as only Alice carries out measurements on her side?
(1) Note, however, that E.T. Jaynes supports a realist interpretation of physics and its role despite, paradoxically, his insistence on the importance of Bayesian inference and the broad development he gave to this approach (cf. Maxent)

Or you could go with the high school interpretation and acknowledge that every time you make a measurement the quantum of energy that was in the system is gone and that the system doesn't exist anymore after that. That would be 100% compatible with actual physical phenomenology. It is also very boring because it completely eliminates a century of irrelevant speculation about the qualities of quanta in a line of theoretical reasoning that starts you off by completely ignoring actual physics.

@FlatterMann Yes and it's boring and ignores physics because it offers absolutely no physical explanation as to how/why the system so called collapses.

@BillAlsept Nothing ever collapses. Energy gets transferred irreversibly between two systems. What the second system is, is a choice by the physicist. Nature can't know anything about that choice a-priori. There is so much utter confusion about what is "nature" and what is "man made" in quantum mechanics that it's not even funny.

@Flatterman all you need to remember is that something is really physically happening and there is no weird magic going on. One day it will be completely and PHYSICALLY explained and I bet we find it's a waveless theory based on photon particles. Photons just need to be taken more seriously.

@BillAlsept I am taking photons perfectly seriously, as the small amounts of energy that systems exchange between each other. That's what the theory says they are, that's what shows up in experiments. What never shows up in experiments are quanta without irreversible energy exchanges. Why talk about something invisible? This is science. We describe what we see, not what we don't.

@Flatterman, I'm not quite sure what you mean by "quanta without irreversible energy exchanges." Could you clarify? My main point is that, upon careful consideration, photons (as particles) is the only model that can physically explain every light phenomenon and every experiment.

@BillAlsept There are no photons either in theory or experiment unless the energy of a photon has been exchanged between the electromagnetic field and an external system like a source or a detector. That's what the Born rule is all about and that is what we observe in the lab. Nobody has ever observed a single photon without there having been a single photon detector like a photomultiplier tube.

@FlatterMann Other than maybe inside a black hole, there is not a single cubic centimeter in the whole universe that's not filled with billions of individual  photons passing through it from every conceivable direction.

@BillAlsept That may be your intuition, but it is not reality. In reality for there to be a photon, a quantum of energy has to be detected in actuality. Physics is not the description of imaginary little balls flying around in space. It's the description of actual measurements in nature. A measurement requires an actual irreversible energy exchange. Without that it's all just human imagination going wild.

@FlatterMann, well that's just silly and I don't know what else to say if you don't believe in photons. Photons are well-documented and have been measured countless times. A quantum of energy is a photon, and just like the moon exists whether we see it or not, photons exist regardless of our detection. While photons are indeed packets of energy, describing them as little balls isn't accurate.

@BillAlsept I don't have to believe in photons. I have measured many trillions of them. I have no idea when physics became a matter of belief. To me it was always about measurement and every measurement in physics is an irreversible energy transfer. It can't be anything else.

@FlatterMann I guess I don't understand your point.

@BillAlsept Photons are not some theoretical concept. We can observe them with an almost trivial amount of experimental hardware thanks to Hamamatsu's catalog of photomultiplier tubes and microchannel plates. But they are only real if such a device (or its physics equivalent of an irreversibly absorbing system) is actually absorbing the energy from the quantized em field. The theory is very clear about that. The Born rule is not just some unfortunate appendage to a theory in which photons exist independently of their emission or absorption. It's the actual center of the theory.
